# Snake Game: how not to make it possible for the fruit to spawn in the same position as the body

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This is my first question and I apologize if it's not posed as it should be in advance.

So, I'm trying to make the fruits (I also call them apples in code) spawn on a position that is different from the snake body just like the title says. The problem is that I don't know how to check if the coordinates of the new fruit is not equal to each of the body parts of the snake.

```
public void newApple() {
    tempX = random.nextInt(width/unitSize)*unitSize;
    tempY = random.nextInt(height/unitSize)*unitSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
        if (tempX != x[i] && tempY != y[i]){    
            appleX = tempX;
            appleY = tempY;
        }
        else {
            newApple();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've figured so far: I'm using 2 temp variables that will correspond to a random position in the frame and then I want to check if those are not equal to each position of the snake. The if condition inside the for loop just checks for x[0] and y[0] which are the coordinates of the head of my snake though.

This is what's inside the `paintComponent()` method to draw the apple.

```
//drawing apple
if (appleX != null && appleY != null) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, unitSize, unitSize);
}
```

Down below is my entire 2 classes of the project if you may need it.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGame();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createGame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    final int width = 600;
    final int height = 600;
    final int unitSize = 25;
    final int maxNumberOfUnits = (width*height)/(unitSize*unitSize);
    int[] x = new int[maxNumberOfUnits];
    int[] y = new int[maxNumberOfUnits];
    int bodyParts = 2;
    Integer appleX, appleY, tempX, tempY;
    int score = 0;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running;
    int delay = 175;
    Timer timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    Random random = new Random();
    Font font1 = new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40);
    Font font2 = new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 75);

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    MyPanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(16, 16, 16));
        setFocusable(true);
        timer.start();
        running = true;
        newApple();
        x[0] = 10*unitSize;
        y[0] = 10*unitSize;
        x[1] = 9*unitSize;
        y[1] = 10*unitSize;

        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    case 37:
                        if (direction !='R') {
                            direction = 'L';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        if (direction !='D') {
                            direction = 'U';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        if (direction !='L') {
                            direction = 'R';
                        }
                        break;
                    case 40:
                        if (direction !='U') {
                            direction = 'D';
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void moveSnake() {
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i-1];
            y[i] = y[i-1];
        }
        switch (direction) {
            case 'U':
                y[0] -= unitSize;
                break;
            case 'D':
                y[0] += unitSize;
                break;
            case 'L':
                x[0] -= unitSize;
                break;
            case 'R':
                x[0] += unitSize;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void newApple() {
        tempX = random.nextInt(width/unitSize)*unitSize;
        tempY = random.nextInt(height/unitSize)*unitSize;

        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
            if (tempX != x[i] && tempY != y[i]){
                appleX = tempX;
                appleY = tempY;
            }
            else {
                newApple();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (running) {
            /*
                //drawing a matrix
                for (int i = 1; i < height/unitSize; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i*unitSize, width, i*unitSize);
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < width/unitSize; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i*unitSize, 0, i*unitSize, height);
                }
            */

            //drawing apple
            if (appleX != null && appleY != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, unitSize, unitSize);
            }

            //drawing snake
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
                g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], unitSize, unitSize);
            }

            //drawing score
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(font1);
            FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: " + score, (width-metrics1.stringWidth("Score: " + score))/2, g.getFont().getSize());
        }
        else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(font1);
            FontMetrics metrics1 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: " + score, (width-metrics1.stringWidth("Score: " + score))/2, g.getFont().getSize());

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(font2);
            FontMetrics metrics2 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Game Over", (width-metrics2.stringWidth("Game Over"))/2, height/2);
        }
    }

    public void checkApple() {
        if (x[0]==appleX && y[0]==appleY) {
            score++;
            bodyParts++;
            newApple();
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {

        //body
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            if (x[0] == x[i] && y[0] == y[i]) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        if (x[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (x[0] > width) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (y[0] < 0) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (y[0] > height) {
            running = false;
        }
        if (!running) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (running) {
            checkApple();
            moveSnake();
            checkCollisions();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _spawn_? Do you mean you want to draw a new apple on the screen?

Comment: Yes, I mean to draw an apple on the screen, but as the question states I don't want it to be in a position where the body of the snake is

Comment: Basically I want the if close in the newApple() method to check all the i of the loop (which are the body parts of the snake) and then set the temp variables to the real coordinates of the apple. That code though just checks for the first one though and I can't figure another way, so everything might be wrong from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a recursive call. Method `newApple()` should not call itself. You need a loop.

1. Generate values for `tempX` and `tempY`.
2. For each part of the snake check whether `tempX` equals the snake body part `x[i]` and also `tempY` equals `y[i]`.
3. If at least one part of the snake body equals the coordinates `tempX` and `tempY`, go back to step 1, above.
4. If none of the snake body parts equals the coordinates, assign the generated coordinates to the "apple".

This is method `newApple()`

```
public void newApple() {
    boolean ok = false;
    while (!ok) {
        ok = true;
        tempX = random.nextInt(width/unitSize)*unitSize;
        tempY = random.nextInt(height/unitSize)*unitSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
            if (tempX == x[i] && tempY == y[i]) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok) {
            appleX = tempX;
            appleY = tempY;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have an array of all the location of body parts of snakes as any body part could do collision (As if the snake collide then it's game over).

You can use the same Array for fruit respawn just ensuring that it is not in the array.

Comment: Yes I already have 2 arrays for each of the x and y coordinates of my snake

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only check if the apple is in the first body parts index.
You need to complete the for loop before checking if the apple can be placed.

```
boolean applePlacementOk = true;
while(true){
    applePlacementOk = true;
    tempX = random.nextInt(width/unitSize)*unitSize;
    tempY = random.nextInt(height/unitSize)*unitSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
        if (tempX == x[i] && tempY == y[i]){    
            applePlacementOk = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(applePlacementOk){
       break;
    }
}
appleX = tempX;
appleY = tempY;
```

Edit: Sorry about SO. This should work better

Edit2: I notice it's essentially the same answer as Abra, now.

Comment: looked really good to me to at first cause that was exactly what I needed but sometimes when the snake bumps into an apple, I get a StackOverflowError :(

Answer (score 0):

You should verify whether `tempX` and `tempY` match the values in the `x` and `y` `arrays` and call `newApple()` if they do and break out of the loop.

This means, that if you reach the end of the loop, no matches were found. You can then safely set the apple's `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
public void newApple() {
    tempX = random.nextInt(width/unitSize)*unitSize;
    tempY = random.nextInt(height/unitSize)*unitSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
        if (tempX == x[i] && tempY == y[i]){    
            newApple();
            break;
        }
        if ( i == bodyParts - 1 ) {
            appleX = tempX;
            appleY = tempY;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `newApple()` is called after the snake has eaten an apple. There is only ever one apple on the screen at a time. After the snake has eaten the only apple, method `newApple()` **must** assign values to `appleX` and `appleY` otherwise there will be no apples on the screen and I don't think that is the intention. After the snake has eaten the apple, another apple must appear. Your `newApple()` method may not assign new values to `appleX` and `appleY`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would try to avoid recursion and create a separate function to calculate if a coordinate collides with the snake's body.

A basic idea would be like this:

```
newApple()
- randomize a new coordinate x,y
- while overlapsWithSnake(x,y)
  - randomize a new coordinate x,y

overlapsWithSnake(x,y)
- iterate through all snake coordinates
  - if coordinate is the same, return true
- return false
```

Now, I need to point out that the algorithm does not consider when there is no more free space in the screen (the end of the game).

Additionally, this algorithm takes more and more time to find an available coordinate as the snake's body grows. What you could do to improve that is the following:

```
newApple()
- assign the result of getAvailableSpaces() to a list
- if the list is empty, then is game over
- else, randomize a number between 0 and list size - 1 as p
- select the coordinate at position p of the list

getAvailableSpaces()
- create logic to return a list of all free coordinates
```